# Implemetation of Daubechis Wavelet using pywavelet

Tags: wavelet

I tried to find the wavelet coeffcient of a 128* 128 size image with DB2 (Daubechis-4 wavelet)

will give four filtered image with size (65*65)...

my doubt is that actualy it should be 64 * 64...in the case of haar...it is giving 64 *64

also db1 it is 64 *64

so can you help me how it comes 65*65  instead of 64*64